# How to create a new column in Pandas using two existing columns *and* position the new column in a certain position in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data in a **csv file**:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

the_data = """
ABC,2016-6-9 0:00,95,"{'//PurpleCar': [115L], '//YellowCar': [403L]}","{'GBP/NOK PAWS': [151L], 'CAD/EUR': [41L], 'EDM8-EDM9': [1833L]}"   
ABC,2016-6-10 0:00,100,"{'//PurpleCar': [219L], '//YellowCar': [381L]}","{'FBTPM5 2015-06-08': [472L], 'HKD/MXN': [0L], 'AUD/SEK DEWS': [19482L]}"   
ABC,2016-6-11 0:00,27,"{'//PurpleCar': [572L], '//YellowCar': [184L]}","{'V 2.000 03/31/25': [759L], 'AUD/JPY': [742L], 'AUD/SEK PAWS': [1784L]}"   
ABC,2016-6-12 0:00,41,"{'//PurpleCar': [80L], '//YellowCar': [2011L]}","{'CAR/FIN SWAP': [151L], 'HKD/MXN': [41L], 'RU4': [5829L]}"   
ABC,2016-6-13 0:00,19,"{'//PurpleCar': [32L], '//YellowCar': [15L]}","{'TRY/CHY OIS': [673L], 'NZD/MXN': [582L], 'AUD/SEK PAPS': [4846242L]}"   
DEF,2016-6-9 0:00,8,"{'//PurpleCar': [19L], '//BlackCar': [17L]}","{'ULM5-ULU5 2015-06-19': [18L], 'HKD/MXN': [64L], 'USD/JPY OPTS': [14714L]}"   
DEF,2016-6-10 0:00,2,"{'//PurpleCar': [32L], '//BlackCar': [15L]}","{'U 4.500 2/15/14': [151L], 'FVU6-FVZ6 2016-09-30': [194], 'AUD/SEK': [0L]}"   
DEF,2016-6-11 0:00,20,"{'//PurpleCar': [32L], '//BlackCar': [15L]}","{'EUR/JPY': [158L], 'ARS/MXN': [562L], 'GBP/JPY PAWS': [1759L]}"   
DEF,2016-6-12 0:00,241,"{'//PurpleCar': [28L], '//BlackCar': [96L]}","{'GBP/NOK OIS': [319], 'HKD/SAG': [103L], 'USD/INR': [3L]}"  
DEF,2016-6-13 0:00,400,"{'//PurpleCar': [32L], '//BlackCar': [15L]}","{'TNM6 2016-06-21': [193], 'EDH9': [1713L], 'GZ5': [0]}"
"""
```

As we can see from the first row of this data set, there are TWO dictionaries within double quotation marks and separated by a comma:

```
"{'//PurpleCar': [115L], '//YellowCar': [403L]}"
```

and

```
"{'GBP/NOK PAWS': [151L], 'CAD/EUR': [41L], 'EDM8-EDM9': [1833L]}"
```

I then manipulate the data frame as follows to deal with the fact that the dictionaries themselves are variable-length and the key values are dynamic:

```
fixed_columns = pd.read_csv(StringIO(the_data),
                            names=["Company", "Date", "Value", "Cars_str",
                                       "Currency_str"])


cars = fixed_columns["Cars_str"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
del fixed_columns["Cars_str"]

currencies = fixed_columns["Currency_str"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
del fixed_columns["Currency_str"]

def get_single_item(list_that_always_has_single_item):
    v, = list_that_always_has_single_item
    return v

def extract_car_name(car_str):
    assert car_str.startswith("//"), car_str
    return car_str[2:]

def extract_instrument_name(currency_str):
    assert currency_str.startswith(""), currency_str
    return currency_str[2:]


dynamic_column_01 = cars.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({
            extract_car_name(k): get_single_item(v) 
            for k, v in x.items()
    }))

dynamic_column_02 = currencies.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({
            extract_instrument_name(k): get_single_item(v) 
            for k, v in x.items()
    }))


result = pd.concat([fixed_columns, dynamic_column_01, dynamic_column_02], axis=1)
result
```

**MY QUESTION**:  I'd like to be able to take the `Value` column, multiply it by a certain coefficient and then place the new column immediately after the `Value` column (and just before the first dictionary).  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage that new columns get placed at the end by computing `MultipliedValue` from `fixed_columns` right after you have parsed and deleted the `Cars_str` and `Currency_str` columns:

```
...

cars = fixed_columns["Cars_str"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
del fixed_columns["Cars_str"]

currencies = fixed_columns["Currency_str"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
del fixed_columns["Currency_str"]

coeff = 1.3
fixed_columns['MultipliedValue'] = coeff * fixed_columns["Value"]

...

result = pd.concat([fixed_columns, dynamic_column_01, dynamic_column_02], axis=1)
result.columns
```

Output:

```
Index(['Company', 'Date', 'Value', 'MultipliedValue', 'BlackCar', 'PurpleCar',
       'YellowCar', '2.000 03/31/25', '4', '4.500 2/15/14', '5', 'D/EUR',
       'D/INR', 'D/JPY', 'D/JPY OPTS', 'D/MXN', 'D/SAG', 'D/SEK', 'D/SEK DEWS',
       'D/SEK PAPS', 'D/SEK PAWS', 'H9', 'M5-ULU5 2015-06-19', 'M6 2016-06-21',
       'M8-EDM9', 'P/JPY PAWS', 'P/NOK OIS', 'P/NOK PAWS', 'R/FIN SWAP',
       'R/JPY', 'S/MXN', 'TPM5 2015-06-08', 'U6-FVZ6 2016-09-30', 'Y/CHY OIS'],
      dtype='object')
```